# Trouble decoding documents from byte array to write to file

Tags: c#, base64, arrays, memorystream

I'm retrieving a byte[] from an SAP system and attempting to decode the array back into the source file format (either pdf, text, jpg, or doc). However after multiple attempts, when opening the newly created temp file, the file contents are the encoded values (I'm using a text file for testing).

The code I'm using is returning a path back to a created object, and my method is below.

```
private string DecodeFromBytes(byte[] fileContents)
    {
        DocumentFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
        //FileStream tempFile = File.OpenWrite(DocumentFilePath);

        string bytesString = Convert.ToBase64String(fileContents);
        
        // Used for Checking.
        // This is the exact same as the passed fileContents value. 
        byte[] convertedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(bytesString);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(convertedBytes, 0, convertedBytes.Length);

        ms.Write(convertedBytes, 0, convertedBytes.Length);

        using (FileStream tempFile = new FileStream(DocumentFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            //byte[] tempBytes = new byte[ms.Length];
            //tempFile.Write(convertedBytes, 0, convertedBytes.Length);
            ms.WriteTo(tempFile);
        }
        
        //tempFile.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        //tempFile.Close();

        return DocumentFilePath;
    }
```

The Encoded text being saved is also improper; there are trailing "A's". I'm guessing as padding on empty bytes? Below is what is being returned, and what *should* be returned.

### Encoded Text

> 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

## What the file should read

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.
> Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh
> elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris.
> Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla.
> Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra,
> per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.

I'm positive I'm forgetting a step, I just don't know where. Any help/hints would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to tell *why* you're converting to base64 at all. Why aren't you just using `File.WriteAllBytes(DocumentFilePath, fileContents)`?

Comment: I'm converting to Base64 so the user can view a selected file in a WPF application.

using `File.WriteAllBytes(DocumentFilePath, fileContents)`, I'm still returning the exact same as the encoded text above.

Comment: But you're not using the base64 version other than to convert back to bytes...

Comment: @JonSkeet , you're right. That's why I feel like I'm chasing my tail! What am I doing wrong in trying to write to bytes to a readable text file?

Comment: If your current code is writing out the base64-encoded version, then it sounds like you're being passed *in* the base64-encoded version.

Comment: @JonSkeet, you're absolutely right! I went back to my SAP source code, and the parameters being passed used the `code` 'SSFC_BASE64_ENCODE' function. 

That would explain the tail chasing.

Answer (score 0):

These 'A' chars are equalient to 0. It seems like your `fileContents` array is 510 bytes length with trailing zeros. Here's a code that replicates the problem:

```
var str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. 
Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh 
elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. 
Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.";
// str's length is much lower
var bytes = new byte[510];
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str, 0, str.Length, bytes, 0);
// Value of output is exactly the same as yours
var output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

But this code will give you an expected result:

```
var str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. 
Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh 
elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. 
Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, 
per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero.";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
var output = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Comment: Your code gives me the correct Base64 string, and eliminates those pesky trails. 

Now, I'm left trying to figure out how to save the bytes into a readable text file (or pdf, in needed).

Comment: @sithlordjake I'm not sure about what you are trying to do at all. Your method is called DecodeFromBytes(), but it actually encodes fileContents to base64.

Comment: I believe I have tunnel vision. What I'm trying to do is retrieve a byte[] and write the bytes to a temporary file for displaying purposes, and be able to view it properly (ie, text to text, image to image, pdf to pdf).

I'm using this method to create a temporary URL for viewing of my object. The other two parameters, of the object, is file extension and title.

Comment: This seems to work, using your example provided. `code` FileStream fs = new FileStream(DocumentFilePath,FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            fs.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
fs.Close();

I'm guessing, the trouble is with the empty bytes. It would seems SAP adds 0's to pad out an array. I'll try looping, or copying the array, and truncating the offending zeros.